# Wait for Form Mouse click

Tags: c#

i have a while loop and every time each cycle ends, i print a mesagebox to show the result. when the "ok" button is clicked, the loop continues. What i want is to print my result to a textbox in the main form and the loop will continue when a mouse click is captured in the main form. 
Any idea?

code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path)); //read file
        string line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string iw = encode.I_type(line);     //doWork
            textBox1.Text = (iw);
            label6.Text = (iw.Length).ToString();
            string strHex = encode.add_digits(Convert.ToInt32(iw, 2).ToString("X"), 8);

            textBox2.Text = strHex;
            MessageBox.Show(line); // when hit ok, goes at the begining of the while loop

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to match your pattern:

```
private StreamReader sr;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path)); //read file
    ProcessOneLine();
}
private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessOneLine();
}
private void ProcessOneLine()
{
    if ( sr == null )
        return;
    string line = string.Empty;
    line = sr.ReadLine()
    if ( line == null )
    {
        sr = null;
        return;
    }
    string iw = encode.I_type(line);     //doWork
    textBox1.Text = (iw);
    label6.Text = (iw.Length).ToString();
    string strHex = encode.add_digits(Convert.ToInt32(iw, 2).ToString("X"), 8);

    textBox2.Text = strHex;
}
```

Comment: it works but this code can be used when the input file has only one line.. In my input file i have a source code that has to be encoded. How can i use this for multiple lines and read file line by line? thank you

Comment: @StavrosAfxentis - this DOES reat the file line by line. Just keep clicking the "Next" button to read the next line.